# Problem accessing prop to change color of button conditionally

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props

What I am trying to achieve is this: I want to change the color of the buttons when you click on them depending on the type of activity. For instance if you click on a button that has activity "concentration" the specific style class for the activity type should be applied when you click on the button. What I am struggling with is to access the activity.type in my changeStyle function. How do I access the activity type and get the button to change color based on the activity type?

**Game.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Game = () => {
    const [activityStyle, setActivityStyle] = useState("activity");

    const zones = [
        {id: 1, name: "Concentration", styleType: "concentration-zone"},
        {id: 2, name: "Communication", styleType: "communication-zone"},
        {id: 3, name: "Collaboration", styleType: "collaboration-zone"},
        {id: 4, name: "Chill Out", styleType: "chill-out-zone"},
        {id: 5, name: "Camp", styleType: "camp-zone"}
    ]
    const activities = [
        {id: 1, name: "Code", type: "concentration"},
        {id: 2, name: "Teams Meeting", type: "communication"},
        {id: 3, name: "Make a phone call", type: "camp"},
        {id: 4, name: "Work shop", type: "collaboration"},
        {id: 5, name: "Coffee break", type: "chillout"}
    ]

    const changeActivityStyle = () => {
       
        
         if (activityType === "concentration") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-concentration"); 
           }
         if (activityType === "communication") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-communication");
         }
         if (activityYype === "camp") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-camp");
         }
         if (activityType === "chillout") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-chill-out");
         } 
         return;
     };

    return (
            <section className="game-area">
                {zones.map((zone =>
                    <div className="zone" id={zone.styleType} key={zone.id}>
                        <p>{zone.name}</p>
                    </div>
                    ))}
                    <div className="activity-container">
                        {activities.map((activity => 
                            <button className={activityStyle} 
                                    onClick={changeActivityStyle} 
                                    key={activity.id} 
                                    activityType={activity.type}
                                    >
                                <p>{activity.name}</p>
                            </button>))}
                    </div>        
            </section>
        );

      
};

export default Game;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `changeActivityStyle` method like this:

```
 /* create reactive state variable to hold the index of the activity clicked */
 const [clickedActivityIndex, setClickedActivityIndex] = useState(-1);

 const changeActivityStyle = (activityType, index) => {
       /* set the index provided by the click handler as active index */
       setClickedActivityIndex(index);

       // access activityType and do whatever you want


        
         if (activityType === "concentration") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-concentration"); 
           }
         if (activityType === "communication") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-communication");
         }
         if (activityYype === "camp") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-camp");
         }
         if (activityType === "chillout") {
             setActivityStyle("activity-chill-out");
         } 
         return;
     };
```

and in `JSX` and provide `activity.type` and the clicked element's `index` as argument to this method:

```
 <div className="activity-container">
     {activities.map((activity,index) => 
     <button className={clickedActivityIndex === index ? activityStyle : ''}
     onClick={() => changeActivityStyle(activity.type, index)} 
     key={activity.id} 
     activityType={activity.type}>
     <p>{activity.name}</p>
     </button>)}
 </div>
```

Comment: Tried this but then I get the following error: 
        
 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: I have updated my answer, `onClick` should have been an inline function like this: `onClick={() => changeActivityStyle(activity.type)} `

Comment: This sort of helped. Now the color changes but for all the buttons and not only for the button that is clicked. How do I apply the new class only on the clicked button?

Comment: That's whole different story, I updated the answer again with new code. It should give you an idea how to implement the styles conditionally when clicked. Also, if my answer was helpful, consider marking it as an accepted answer.